# How can I use the same filter in Excel (for Mac) twice on the same sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, cells

I am working with a basic filter in an Excel sheet that I have on page layout. Both pages will have to have the exact same filter (it's separate as one page serves as a purchase order and the following page with technical details) but I don't want to have to choose the same filters twice in the same document to avoid errors.

Is there a way to link the first filter to the second one?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that your only option for applying filters automatically across multiple worksheets is to use VBA code.  Writing that or explaining how to do it is beyond the scope of SuperUser, but you can find several examples ([such as this one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/how-can-i-apply-a-filter-to-all-sheets-at-the-same/d5b61502-fc74-4e6f-95b8-1bc880c0a40d?auth=1)) with a quick google search.  If you're having problems implementing that, you can always come back here or to StackOverflow with your specific difficulties.